# How to stop HTTP request which send data to Mixpanel from Viewer3D.js

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Viewer3D.js send data to Mixpanel.
Does Viewer3D.js has an option to stop sending to Mixpanel?

[Google Chrome DevTools - Network1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuR4f.png)

[Google Chrome DevTools - Network2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9tGk.png)

[Google Chrome DevTools - Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtIXZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Now with the upcoming Viewer v7.18 (to be released soon as of now) it's possible to opt out of data collection - and it defaults to opted out...

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.analytics.optIn()
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.analytics.optOut()
```

**Original Answer**

Viewer v7.16 and onwards introduced user behavior collection which is by default enabled (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id1) for relevant statements) and we are still working on an interface to opt out of it.

While we do that you can fall back to v7.14 or earlier unless you strongly require the latest features as of v7.14- let me know if that's the case and I'd try figure out a workaround for you ...

```
<script src='http://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=7.14'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. I'm happy. But, if i get any problems with this matter, please shall we talk again on email.